# Assign value from LiveData inside ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

Is it possible to assign a value from a LiveData from within a ViewModel? I want to assign the value of exercise to dayOfWeek when the ViewModel is initialized however the value is always null:

```
class UpdateViewModel(
    exerciseKey: Long = 0L,
    dataSource: ExerciseDatabaseDao
    ) : ViewModel() {

        val database = dataSource
        private val exercise: LiveData<Exercise> = database.getExerciseWithId(exerciseKey)

        private val dayOfWeek = MutableLiveData(exercise.value!!.dayOfWeek) //NullPointerException

}
```

DAO:

```
@Dao
interface ExerciseDatabaseDao {

    ...

    @Query("SELECT * from exercise_list_table WHERE exerciseId = :key")
    fun getExerciseWithId(key: Long): LiveData<Exercise>
}
```

From what I understand LiveData isn't initialized until there are observers, is there any way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume `database.getExerciseWithId(exerciseKey)` is an _asynchronous_ call and thus, you are immediately getting NPE for `excercise#value()`. You need to use its observer and then try fetching `dayOfWeek` there; or make the call synchronous. Please post your `ExerciseDatabaseDao#getExerciseWithId(int)` code snippet so that we can understand how it's being fetched.

Comment: Sure, Just updated the post.

Comment: You can't do this without blocking the main thread, which risks an ANR error. The value of the LiveData from the DAO will arrive sometime after you get the LiveData reference, which is too soon because your other property is initialized immediately when your ViewModel is instantiated.

Comment: Please allow me to correct myself. Since, you are using Room database queries which are [mandatorily run asynchronously](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries), you cannot make it synchronous. You need to **register** live data observer callback for `exercise` in your activity/fragment lifecycle and then query the database using `getExerciseWithId(long)`. I wouldn't use such implicit calls inside viewmodel to fetch data from database layer.